# Postgres extract JSON keyed by specific column

Tags: json, postgresql

I have data in Postgres (10.4) in the form of

```
id | my_json
-----------------------------------
1  | {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,3]}
2  | {"a": 3, "b": 5, "c": [2,3,4]}
```

I can output the data as JSON like this:

```
WITH l AS (SELECT id, my_json as data FROM table)
SELECT to_json(l) FROM l;
```

and i get:

```
{"id": 1, "data": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,3]}}
{"id": 2, "data": {"a": 3, "b": 5, "c": [2,3,4]}}
```

But is there a way to output the data, keyed by the `id`?

Like this:

```
{"1": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,3]}}
{"2": {"a": 3, "b": 5, "c": [2,3,4]}}
```

**EDIT:**

The answer from @Silvio Baez put me on the right track and I realized this is not actually exactly what i needed.

I actually want the result to be a merge of the objects like:

```
{
 "1": {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,3]}, 
 "2": {"a": 3, "b": 5, "c": [2,3,4]}
}
```

And this is achieved in a similar way with:

```
SELECT json_object_agg(id, data::json) FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you like this solution. It consists of using the function [jsonb_build_object (VARIADIC "any")](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE).

**Example**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE json_table (
    id integer,
    my_json json
);

INSERT INTO json_table (id, my_json) VALUES
    (1, '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,3]}'),
    (2, '{"a": 3, "b": 5, "c": [2,3,4]}');

SELECT json_build_object(id,my_json) FROM json_table;
```

**Result**

```
{"1" : {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": [1,2,3]}}
{"2" : {"a": 3, "b": 5, "c": [2,3,4]}}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This works. I'm putting it as an answer even thought this is actually not what I want, but I realize I did not ask the question properly. Will edit my question and add an answer for it.